# Is there a lua equivalent of Scala's map or C#'s Select function?

Tags: select, dictionary, lua

I'm looking for a nice way to do a map / select on a Lua table.

eg. I have a table :

```
myTable = {
  pig = farmyard.pig,
  cow = farmyard.bigCow,
  sheep = farmyard.whiteSheep,
}
```

How do I write myTable.map(function(f) f.getName)? [Assuming all farmyard animals have names]

ie. apply the function to all elements in the table.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

write your own version? there isn't a built-in function to do this in lua.

```
function map(tbl, f)
    local t = {}
    for k,v in pairs(tbl) do
        t[k] = f(v)
    end
    return t
end

t = { pig = "pig", cow = "big cow", sheep = "white sheep" }
local newt = map(t, function(item) return string.upper(item) end)

table.foreach(t, print)
table.foreach(newt, print)
```

produces:

```
pig pig
sheep   white sheep
cow big cow
pig PIG
cow BIG COW
sheep   WHITE SHEEP
```

Comment: Since `string.upper` is a function of one parameter, you could further simplify it to `local newt = map(t, string.upper)` ;)

Comment: @MichalKottman i know that, i did it this way to show an example of how to pass an anonymous function directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Lua 5.1, you can use `table.foreach()`:

```
a = { 1, 2, 3 }
table.foreach(a, function(k,v) a[k] = v + 2 end)
table.foreach(a, print)
-- 1    3
-- 2    4
-- 3    5
```

This is deprecated, though, and no longer present in 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution using metatables:

```
map = function (old_t, f)
    return setmetatable({}, {
        __index = function (new_t, k)
            new_t[k] = f(old_t[k])
            return new_t[k]
        end
    })
end
```

The resulting table calculates each entry only when it is necessarily, essentially being a lazy table.

This means that it will also work on infinite lazy lists and tables, but there is a caveat - namely that if `f` doesn't always return the same result for the same input, then as the function calls are delayed then the resulting table might act differently depending on how differently `f` behaves when the table is created, and when each key is first indexed.

Comment: An interesting trick - but perhaps you should be more clear that this means that the tables are permanently linked with what is effectively a dynamic mapping, yes?  And that it needs to call function every time you use the entries, as opposed to mapping it once.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all the other answers provide a slow map function. You will be able to see the performance difference when you have more than just a few elements in table.

This is the fastest map() function in pure lua -

```
function map(f, t)
    local t1 = {}
    local t_len = #t
    for i = 1, t_len do
        t1[i] = f(t[i])
    end
    return t1
end
```

It doesn't use the # operator in loop for comparison nor does it do `t1[#t1+1]`. both of which are slow.

PS: This code was taken [from this article](https://uiv.me/blog/lua-map/)

Comment: Again - answered 7 years prior and far more completely, your answer only deals with lists and not the hash part of a table.

Comment: There is no benefit caching the result of the `#` operator in a variable, as expressions of the `for` statement are evaluated only once. Lua documentation: [Numeric for](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html).

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of a map function in lua -

```
function(f, t)
    local o = {}
    for i = 1, #t do
        o[#o + 1] = f(t[i])
    end
    return o
end
```

Please Note: the above implementation is unoptimized. It should work for your purpose. However if you want one of the fastest implementation of the map() function in lua you can check this out - [Lua Map Function](https://web.archive.org/web/20190225223533/https://uiv.me/blog/2019/02/25/lua-map/)
It contains code and explanation.

Comment: Way to poorly (and incorrectly) copy the answer of a question from 7 years prior???